# Get timepicker value while scrolling and display in textview

Tags: android, android-intent, textview, actionlistener, timepicker

I used the onTimeChanged listener to receive from timepicker but when i try to display it in textview, im getting error saying "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setText(CharSequence) from the type TextView", even though i declared global variables. I'm using the listener in onCreate method.

```
    TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener timePickerListener = new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) { 
            hour = selectedHour; 
            minute = selectedMinute; 
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(); 
            sb.append(hour).append(":").append(minute); 
            str=sb.toString(); 
            TextView.setText(str);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code please, most likely an issue with where you are calling `setText` from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the instance of the `TextView` which you want to change. Try doing this within the handler, as I'm not sure where you are defining `TextView`.

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
if (myTextView != null)
     farm.setText(str);
```